# Change Color of Segoe UI Font Button Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

How can I change it so that any button I create for my Windows 8 app has a differently-colored Segoe UI glyph than the default (white)? I tried the following to no avail:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Button" Content="&#xE17F;">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Fill="red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

My hopes were that this would create a solid red circle for a button rather than a white one, but it renders nothing at all instead. Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<<Button .... Foreground="Red" />` doesn't work or you want glyph only in diff color the round border as white ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Foreground` property.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Foreground="Red"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Button" Content="&#xE17F;" />
```